# With 2 maps on same material i am not able to see and paint on 2nd map in texture mode

Tags: texture-painting

I have applied 2 maps to same material, they use same UV. In texture paint mode 3D view with solid display. I can only see 1st texture map (topmost in the stack) and paint on it.

[image]

But on the contrary in texture paint mode with Texture display mode. I can only see the last image in the stack (in this case Helper overall). But when i paint in 3D view it starts painting on top most image in the textures stack (in this case checkers)

[image]

How do a paint on 2nd texture (in this case Helper overall) in 3D view? I am able to paint by temporarily by moving the texture slot up

[image]

And in texture display mode of texture paint i had to disable 2nd texture to see the first texture

[image]

What is happening ? Is there a right way of doing this?

Comment: you are using the Material tab to pick textures.  That's how things were done up until about a  year ago.   Now slots are used.  When you press 't' for the tool options, there is a tab named "Slots" make your selections from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added two textures to the material as shown in the following image.

[image]

Now you can switch between the textures using the Texture Paint mode Slots tab.  You'll notice that the Slots tab shows up in the tools tab for me.  You can make this happen by shift clicking on a blank area of a tab's working space to pin it so it always shows up regardless of what tab you are currently using.

[image]